# How to send files from telegram bot?

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm coding a Telegram bot and I need to send files to users. I want to get `file_id` of files I want to send. I am following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34366385/10371918).

To get `file_id`, I should send the file to my Telegram bot. The question is how to send files via my bot to itself? (maybe using the API?)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this helps you for any kind of file: Methods like [this one](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html?highlight=send_message#telegram.Bot.send_photo) accept both an integer (chat ID) and a string (@channel_name) for `chat_id`. So with the [bot's username](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html?highlight=send_message#telegram.Bot.name), I guess you could send a message from the bot to itself.

Comment: No, it doesn't work.

Comment: You can NOT send anything from a bot to a bot (itself or other bots).

Answer (score 1):

[You can send files](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files) without `file_id`:

> There are three ways to send files (photos, stickers, audio, media,
>   etc.):
>
> - If the file is already stored somewhere on the Telegram servers, you don't need to reupload it: each file object has a file_id field,
>     simply pass this file_id as a parameter instead of uploading. There
>     are no limits for files sent this way.
> - Provide Telegram with an HTTP URL for the file to be sent. Telegram will download and send the file. 5 MB max size for photos and 20 MB
>     max for other types of content.
> - Post the file using multipart/form-data in the usual way that files are uploaded via the browser. 10 MB max size for photos, 50 MB for
>     other files

You can use `file_id` only if you have already sent it to someone before (using URL or multipart/form-data).

---

So if a list of files you want to send is predefined, "static", you can upload all of them once, get their `file_id`'s (using `getUpdates` method for example), store associations between files and their respective `file_id`'s and finally your bot can use only `file_id` to communicate with users.

On the other hand, if a list of possible files varies, you can send files only via URL or multipart/form-data.

Comment: I have chosen the third method: Post the file using multipart/form-data. I have already seen a lot of questions about this method and nobody could answer directly on it. So can you explain in details this method, please?

Comment: Sure. What's the problem with multipart/form-data?

Comment: @cooleck maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43969042/how-to-send-photo-by-telegram-bot-using-multipart-form-data) (with good answer) helps you?